Comedy from the end of the 80s about a casanvoa
I am looking for a movie from the end of the eighties or perhaps the beginning of the nineties. It is about a man who is a real casanova and he needs to stop the casanova life and settle down. The cover of the movie is showing a babe in only her panties (zoomed in so the waist + little part of legs covers the cover). The main character is balancing on the top of her panties upper edge (so he is shrinked on the cover).
In the movie the main character goes to a party and for some reason he thought it was a masquerade and he comes dressed as Aladin. However, the party was not a masquerade and he consumes a lot of alcohol to feel ok. At one point he tells a woman "Hi, I am aladin, this is my lamp and my wish is to fuck you". And the woman punches him in the face.

You're looking for the Blake Edwards comedy Skin Deep from 1989 with John Ritter.

Zach Hutton is a womanizing, drunken, allelic writer whose life seems to be falling apart at the seams. He's still in love with his ex-wife (whose family can't stand him), writer's block is keeping him from completing his latest novel, and he repeatedly finds himself in trouble of one sort or another with the law, ex-girlfriends, and jealous boyfriends.

At one point he arrives dressed as Aladdin to a formal party that he mistook for a costume party, and after getting drunk, tells a woman:

My name is Zachary Hutton, and my wish is to f@#& you.

The poster fits your description too, though it's a bra he's walking on, not panties. Here's the trailer:




Haha - amazing how quick I got an answer to that one! And of course - you are 100% correct, Skin deep is the movie I am looking for! Thanks Walt!

Was Skin Deep the movie with the "light sabre" fight?

Yes, though I'm not sure if I should link the clip... :/ It's on Youtube, anyway.
